# How was this photo of a shoe suspended above a wet pavement taken?

Tags: technique, product-photography, shooting-technique

[image: Photo obtained from Instagram. Owner: @tobishinobi]

How do you reckon that this photo was taken? What fascinates me is how the shoe was captured just before hitting the ground, and with the focus being sharp and centered on the object.

Photo credits: [@tobishinobi on Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BAzOBFHwKsU/?taken-by=tobishinobi&hl=en)

Comment: Please see [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit your question (and title) accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: You want to know how exactly Tobi did it or how you can recreate a similar image? If you want to know how he did it, why not just ask him? He is on Twitter and obviously Instagram as well. Unless someone here was present, I'm doubting anyone could definitively tell you how it was done. We could guess...

Comment: I already asked him, but never got a response. That's why I asked the question here.

Comment: I've asked him on Twitter where he has a smaller following. Maybe you can add to the request and it might motivate him to give an answer. https://twitter.com/heyvian/status/740588332585885696

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't take the photo so I can't say for sure, but there are a couple of possible answers.  He could have taken several photos (i.e. one without the shoe, one with someone's foot in the shoe holding it up, or one of just the shoe) and photoshopped them together.  It's also possible that there's something behind the shoe that we can't see holding it up.  A third option is that he just dropped the shoe and used a very fast shutter speed with continuous shooting to capture that particular moment.

This tutorial has some good advice on motion shots, including freeze frame that might interest you: http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/camera-shutter-speed.htm

Comment: Have you ever composited a reflection with deflections for places the water surface is curved by the surface tension at the places where items such as the bolts intersect with the water? I highly doubt this image was created by compositing the shoe into the scene captured with the bolts in the water and no reflection at the time it was captured. If it was then there's a lot of CGI going on with the physics of the shape of the water caused by the surface tension that's far beyond the capability of photoshop.

Comment: Perhaps I was confusing on my response, but I was not implying the reflection is Photoshopped. What I was trying to say is that he could have taken a photo without the show and then one with the shoe being held up by something and used the first photo to edit out parts of the second.The 'shoot two photos method' on this is what I'm referring to: http://petapixel.com/2015/02/10/levitation-photography-tutorial/

Comment: My guess is this is a real photo and not photoshop.

Comment: Fishing line and Photoshop are wonderful things.

Answer (score 3):

With a camera. And some post processing. And maybe some CGI.

I'm not saying this is how he did it, but it would be fairly easy to hang the shoe by a thin piece of monofilament fishing line and then remove it in post by cloning in a blurry power pole (Kind of like the one that is exactly where a support line would be) in the far background to cover your tracks. One could even take another image from the same camera position without the shoe and fishing line present and use that entire sky in post.